# HTACCESS - correct syntax to redirect needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I never really understood correctly .htaccess formulas but I could always find something similiar to my needs and modify this. I read a lot of tutorials but in most cases they tell how to do the same things and I cant learn something new. 
Now I faced need of using mod rewrite again and cant find anywhere solution. Hope you can help me with correct syntax.

I have such an adress typed in my browser:

http://www.example.com/pages/test3.php

And I'd like to redirect user to:

http://www.example.com/pages/index.php?p=test3

But (if it is possible) address in browser should remain the first one so the user doesnt know he has been redirected. In other words is that possible with modrewrite to load data from second address as it looked it is first one?

Hope you can help me, i really appreciate it!

Comment: you may find the below info useful. good luck. -d http://pastie.org/5364605

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/index\.php
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)\.php$ /pages/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```